# How to find the limit superior of $(-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}$?

Tags: limsup-and-liminf

If I have a sequence defined as $a_n = (-1)^n + \frac{1}{n}$, how would I find the limit superior?

Comment: Look up an example of how lim sups are calculated. If you don't understand that example, go back to the definition of lim sup. This problem is pretty standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odd terms are non-positive, while even terms are greater than $1$. Hence the limit superior is also the limit superior of the even terms – which converge to $1$. Thus
$$\limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n=1.$$